# casting function pointer from one prototype to another and back?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a base class which contains `WNDPROC` member, but some derived classes such as controls use `SUBCLASSPROC` instead, both of which are function pointers to window procedure, just different prototype.

I want to avoid having 2 members in all derived classes because only one will by used by all instances.

So my question is, can I `reinterpret_cast` from one function pointer to another and then cast back again? is it safe?

for example:

```
SUBCLASSPROC fnptr = /* some function */

WNDPROC data = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(fnptr);

// is this pointer "original_pointer" valid now?
SUBCLASSPROC original_pointer = reinterpret_cast<SUBCLASSPROC>(data);
```

Basically in this example the `data` pointer is only used to store function pointer of different type.

btw. I know I could use templated member, but my design does not allow it, since `data` pointer is a member of yet another structure over which I have no control.

Comment: Yes. If you cast a function pointer to another function pointer and cast it back, you are guaranteed to get the original value back. Of course, you must cast it back before using it. [Citation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#6). Another option is to use a union.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you! your answers as well as blog posts are awesome and straight to the point!

Comment: `std::variant` would possibly be a a safer option

Comment: One another problem introduced now, is that such cast will generate warning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4191 But looks like I'll have to use some pragmas around this, which means pragmas in all caller code, or some function that will do the conversion and set pragmas to be in one place.

Comment: As Raymond suggested, use a union. Casting should be avoided when at all possible.

Comment: Thank you, I'll redesign code to use union which seems most "normal".

Comment: @JonathanPotter Type punning is no better than casting, and I don't see how you can avoid that with a union in (standard) C++.

Comment: A union works because either the WNDPROC or the SUBCLASSPROC member will be active, and the code that reads the value knows which member to use (namely, the active one).